# Data Wrangling in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe df in python

```
Age     product
------------------
21          apple
11          orange
eighteen    mango
35          pineapple
35          122
NA          apple
30          -1
```

I only want numeric columns in age, how would I drop the rows which are not integers.

Similarly in product, I need only strings, how would I drop the values which are not strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly safe way to check numeric values is use `pd.isnumeric(..., errors='coerce')` and then check nulls; Since `pandas` can contain different data types in a single column, `str.isnumeric` returns `NaN` if the value is actual numeric type and it doesn't recognize negative numbers as numeric because python doesn't:

```
isnumeric = lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').notnull()
df[isnumeric(df['Age']) & ~isnumeric(df['product'])]

#  Age    product
#1  21      apple
#2  11     orange
#4  35  pineapple
```

<sub>This method only checks numeric values, you'll need extra logic if you need to check integers.</sub>

Comment: How would I change the logic if I wanted only strings.

Comment: String is a very broad concept. It can be anything from `'123', 'abc'` to `'[1,2,3]'` even `'{a:b}'` as long as they are properly quoted.  If you mean strings with specific characters such as letters, you need regular expression and functions like `str.contains(...)` and `str.match(...)`. For letters, you would need regex like `[a-zA-Z]+` for instance. And use it like `df.product.str.match("[a-zA-Z]+$")`.